# Method Calling Syntax Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I can call a method to set the background colour of a control using:-

`tvNAME.setBackgroundColor(0xFFABCDEF);`

How can I substitute 'tvNAME' for the contents of an array element?

`tvArray[0] = "tvNAME";`

`tvArray[0].setBackgroundColor(0xFFABCDEF);`

I know this syntax isn't correct but it shows what I am trying to do.
I have been all over Google but the problem is, I don't seem to be able to search for the correct question.

Comment: What is the type of tvArray? Here it looks like String array -> tvArray[0] = "tvNAME"; ane here like view array -> tvArray[0].setBackgroundColor(0xFFABCDEF);

Comment: The array is String, tvArray[0] contains the name of the TextView I want to set the colour of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two options.

1. Change your tvArray to be of type TextView.

   `tvArray[0].setText(tvNAME)
   tvArray[0].setBackgroundColor(0xFFABCDEF);`
2. Look for TextView in your layout and update its color

   `for( int i = 0; i < yourLayout.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
       View view = activityLayout.getChildAt(i)
       if (view instanceof TextView && ((TextView) view).getText().equals("tvNAME"))

         ((TextView) view).setBackgroundColor(0xFFABCDEF);
   }`

I would go with option one, IMO it is nicer. If it helped please mark as answered.

Comment: #1 is the perfect solution. I am new to this and hadn't realised that array types could be TextViews, I am only familiar with array types being ints and strings. I can't add a thank you, being a new member so I pass my thanks on here.

Comment: Glad to here that it helped :) Happy coding